# How can I display all days between a range and show count for number of open bugs?

Tags: sql, database

I have a table where I keep bugs and it has the following structure.

```
id, open_date, close_date, severity
```

I'm trying to run a query to show the count for the number of bugs that are open on each day of the month. The query that I have isn't quite what I'm looking for, it shows me the count for the number of bugs opened on a particular day.

Here is my query

```
select COUNT(bg.id), dt.date
from dates as dt
LEFT JOIN Bug as bg on bg.open_date = dt.date
WHERE bg.open_date >= '2017-01-01' AND
      bg.open_date <='2017-01-31'
GROUP BY dt.date
```

I also created a basic date table and populated it with dates. The structure of that table is as follows.

```
date_id, date, day_of_week, month, weekend
```

what do I need to change to get things in this format?

```
2017-01-01 | 3
2017-01-02 | 3
2017-01-03 | 3
2017-01-04 | 1
2017-01-01 | 0
2017-01-01 | 0
2017-01-01 | 0
2017-01-01 | 2
2017-01-01 | 3
2017-01-01 | 4
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this for a specific month:

```
select dt.date, COUNT(bg.id) bug_count
from dates dt
left join Bug bg on dt.date between open_date and close_date
where open_date <= '2017-01-01'
and close_date >= '2017-01-31'
group by 2
```

or this for all months:

```
select COUNT(bg.id) bug_count, dt.date, dt.month
from dates dt
left join Bug bg on dt.date between open_date and close_date
group by 2, 3
```

Note that you need to include both `open_date` and `close_date` in your date range condition